# Angular ngRepeat dynamically create ngModel with $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have this html:

And I want to create dynamically ng-models for these inputs:

```
     <div class="order" ng-repeat="order in newOrders">
          <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="model$index" />{{$index}} please check
     </div>
```

and it's not working.
I there a way to dynamically create ng-model in a input, inside a ng-repeat?

**EDIT**:

The final result is:

> ```
>   <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="model$index" />0 please check
> ```

My expected result is:

> ```
>   <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="model0" />0 please check
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The way you are trying to do its not appropriate, creating separate
>   variable for each element, that will make more maintenance sort of
>   work.

Also this will become messy to when you apply any `filter` on `ng-repeat`. Instead of that you could place that model value inside the `ng-repeat` element which is order here `order`.

```
 <div class="order" ng-repeat="order in newOrders">
     <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="order.value" />{{$index}} please check
 </div>
```

Comment: using ng-model="model[$index]" has no effects. and this value I have to setup before? in the controller?

Comment: @AlvaroJoao Glad to help you..Thanks :)